# « Être plus … que », « être aussi … que » et négation

Tags: négation, comparatifs

> Elles (ne) sont (pas) plus importantes que dans le passé

et

> Elles (ne) sont (pas) aussi importantes que dans le passé

Quelle est la différence entre les deux?
(avec et sans « ne … pas », donc 4 variantes)

Comment: sorry about all the questions before attempting to answer, but are you sure that the notions (and differences between them) that you are dealing with are best captured by "COMME dans le[s] passé" and not "QUE dans le passé"?

Comment: To follow up on @PapaPoule, the formulations you propose hardly sound French. It would be easier to answer your actual point with something like: Elles (ne) sont (pas) plus/aussi importantes que dans le passé.

Comment: The only reason for my 2 questions above (not only the 1st one, but also the 2nd) was that I saw a 5th possible construction to analyze, i.e., the following one using **n’etre plus** (with the “ne” but w/out the “pas”)=**no longer**, which, imo, could be used correctly with “comme” instead of “que”: “Elles ne sont plus importantes comme [elles étaient] avant/dans le passé,” which isn’t really a comparison & means “They are no longer important [un]like in the past [when they were important].” I asked just to clarify these 2 issues & not to suggest that your question/use of "comme" were flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Brièvement

- (ne pas) être plus … que : *(not) to be more … than*
- (ne pas) être aussi … que : *(not) to be as … as*

### Mathématiquement

- être plus … que : `>`
- être aussi … que : `=`
- ne pas être plus … que : `≤`
- ne pas être aussi … que : `≠` (sous-entendu `<`)

### Traduction des exemples

> Elles sont plus importantes que dans le passé.
>   *They are more important than in the past.*

→ Le niveau d'importance a augmenté.

---

> Elles ne sont pas plus importantes que dans le passé.
>   *They are not more important than in the past.*

→ Le niveau d'importance a stagné ou diminué.

---

> Elles sont aussi importantes que dans le passé.
>   *They are as important as in the past.*

→ Le niveau d'importance n'a pas changé.

---

> Elles ne sont pas aussi importantes que dans le passé.
>   *They are not as important as in the past.*

→ Le niveau d'importance a changé (sans autre commentaire, on comprendra qu'il a diminué).

Comment: Juste pour être chiant, la négation en anglais ne devrait pas être juste après le *"to"* ?

Comment: @YohannV. ca me parait plus naturel **not to be** ( en référence de la célèbre citation "*To be, or not to be ? That is the question*" ) :)

Comment: Mmm j'ai une question à poser ! :D

Comment: @YohannV. Je me suis posé la question. Dans une phrase complète, la position va dépendre de la signification que l'on veut donner à la phrase (je n'ai pas d'exemple en tête, mais j'ai déjà rencontré et utilisé les deux, pour des questions d'emphase notamment). Pour l'infinitif, j'avoue que j'ai un doute. Une [question sur english.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/23206) semble indiquer que les deux sont justes et que la position peut effectivement être choisie en fonction de l'effet que l'on souhaite produire.

Comment: @Chop Ok ! Merci pour le lien

Answer (score 3):

> Elles sont plus importantes que dans le passé

et

> Elles sont aussi importantes que dans le passé

expriment respectivement une importance plus grande (que dans le passé) et une importance égale.

> Elles ne sont pas plus importantes que dans le passé

signifie généralement que les choses dont on parle sont également importantes voire moins importantes que dans le passé (importance inférieure ou égale) : l'importance n'a pas augmenté, mais c'est tout ce que l'on sait.

> Elles ne sont pas aussi importantes que dans le passé

signifie que l'importance a diminué entre avant et maintenant : elles sont *moins* importantes que dans le passé.